# How to handle search query with Japanese language with MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I use MySQL Server for Web App JSP, and have a problem with LIKE query in MySQL. 
When i use LIKE query with Katakana type of Japanese language, sometime results don't display correctly.

Example:

```
SELECT  r.report_id, r.user_id, u.user_name
FROM report r JOIN user u ON u.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE r.report_comment LIKE CONCAT('%', 'AC', '%') )
```

In this query, when i type '**AC**' character with **English**, and try to execute this query with Java. Results is correct(1 row returned).

[image]

But when i type '**AC**' character with **Katakana**, and try to execute this query with Java. No rows are found.
[image]

How to handle search query correctly with all of case?

Comment: Does the encoding of your database support Japanese character ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about this.

Comment: When you do a `select`, does Katakana being displayed correctly ?

Comment: Sometime, when i **only** type Katakana character.

Comment: Did you check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html ? Specially the part 'Make sure that the problem is not with the browser or other application, rather than with MySQL', that might be your issue here

Comment: How do you issue these queries? Do you hard-code the queries in a Java source code file, compile and execute? Or is the query generated from user input by your application?

Comment: @ortis Oh my god, it is this issue.Thanks!

Comment: :) I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MySQL CJK faq](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html) contains various tips about how to deal with Japanese character.
The paragraph  *Make sure that the problem is not with the browser or other application, rather than with MySQL* seems to provide fix to your issue.