# How to configure Google Cloud SQL the same as my.ini file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have changed database from MySQL to Google Cloud SQL and have some problem with configuration. This is about CJK character.

With MySQL, i have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482241/how-to-handle-search-query-with-japanese-language-with-mysql). But now, I use Google Cloud SQL, and can't find any solution for this issue. Please help!

About test case, can see in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482241/how-to-handle-search-query-with-japanese-language-with-mysql).

Comment: Could you add more information about what it's failing or you're missing and maybe some test cases. It would be useful for those who have no previous experience with CTK but willing to help you.

Comment: For example, this both works in my Cloud SQL instance
SELECT 'ペ' AS `ペ`; 
SELECT _ucs2 0x30da;

+-----+
| ペ  |
+-----+
| ペ  |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.13 sec)

Comment: @user3852065 You can see some test cases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482241/how-to-handle-search-query-with-japanese-language-with-mysql?lq=1

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of Japanese and can't build that DB myself. Could you upload to pastebin or here a SQL file so that I could create my own DB to play with it?
I guess your question is this one "A.11.12: Why do some LIKE and FULLTEXT searches with CJK characters fail?", isn't it?

Comment: @user3852065 Maybe, but my issue into MySQL has resolved with the part 'Make sure that the problem is not with the browser or other application, rather than with MySQL'. You can check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html

Comment: Yeah, I see, but as far as I try it, I can see the Japanese characters when running the examples in the FAQ. I'm connecting to Cloud SQL instance through MySQL client under Linux.

Comment: @user3852065 Could you try to run on other application again? Doesn't use MySQL client, because when run on MySQL client, it's always correct.

Comment: But then, the issue is not with Cloud SQL but with the application you're using.